# post to sveltekit api and reading the body is producing empty object

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm attempting to use sveltekit api and fetch.

I have a component inside $lib/components/newsletter.svelte

```
<script>

async function postapi(){

let posttheapi = await fetch('api/newsletter',{
  method : "POST",
  credentials : 'include',
  headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-type' : 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
  useremail : "abc@onetwothree.com"
  })
})
let postresults = await posttheapi.json()

console.log("results log +page.svelte index page :", postresults )

}


</script>
<button on:click={postapi}>post api access</button>
```

I get the expected results from the server.

And my api/newsletter/+server.js

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'
export async function POST(requestEvent){
     
    //get the useremail from the body
    let readbody = await requestEvent.request.body
    console.log("requestEvent body log : ", readbody)

    //return this     
    let postresults = "POST handle -- return something..."
    return json(postresults)

}
```

The console.log with requestEvent.body is returning
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }

How do I get the posted "useremail" from the request in my api +server.js post handle?

I read online about data streams and no answer or anyone explaining how to extract the body data which is the whole purpose of posting to a server so you can use the data. I intend to store the useremail in my database. I'm unable to get the useremail from the request???

How do you get the body data in the post handle inside a +server.js in sveltekit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the official documentation [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server-receiving-data). Instead of `.body` you should use `.json()` instead.

However. it is also worth mentioning that [Form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) is the preferable way to handle data submission from browser to server.

```js
<script>
...
export async function POST(requestEvent){
    let readBody = await requestEvent.request.json();
    console.log("requestEvent body log : ", readBody);
    // requestEvent body log :  { useremail: 'abc@onetwothree.com' }
    ...
}
</script>
```

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990443/unable-to-access-request-body-from-the-endpoint-js-in-sveltekit-skeleton-project) you might want to refer to.